# What fluid can I store metal filings in so they do not oxidize?

Tags: metal, alcohols

I am working on an art project that will involve storing filings of various metals (e.g., iron, copper, zinc) in a colorless fluid. I want to prevent the metals from oxidizing for several years, so water is out. I already have 70% isopropyl alcohol. Will this work, or will the remaining 30% water be a problem? If not, what fluid would you suggest?

Comment: I feel like mineral oil is a frequently used, but I don't know if that works for years...

Comment: Mineral oil would be my go to

Comment: And seal the container after backfilling with nitrogen.

Comment: Alcohol reacts slowly with some metals, e.g., aluminum and probably zinc. Since sodium is normally stored under *pure* mineral oil, as others suggest, that might be best. For lower viscosity, try a lighter alkane, e.g. dodecane, or naphtha. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkane **N.B.** flammability hazard: not only will alkanes burn, but finely divided metal is pyrophoric!